# Is there a way to differentiate between normal Activity destruction and one caused by rotation?

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I have an Activity that start some asynctasks. I want these tasks to stop, when my Activity is destroyed "normally" (like calling finish() / the user pressing the back button / etc.), but continue running when the user only rotates the device.

Canceling these tasks, and handling the rotation works just fine, I just can't combine the two.

So is there a way to tell during the "onDestroy()" callback, that the Activity is destroyed because of a configurational change (rotation), or because of some other cause (back button e.g.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [`isChangingConfigurations()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29) on your `Activity`.

Comment: Whoa I missed that one in the docs, exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: @Scythe: Actually, I did too. I heard reference to it a month or two ago. I need to update some books to mention it. :-)

Comment: Sadly it wasn't introduced until API level 11

Comment: @Joseph Earl: That would be why I missed it. :-) Sorry for not catching that when I wrote the original answer. The trick I've used historically is to set a boolean in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, as that is only called when there's a configuration change afoot.

Comment: yes that would have been along the lines of what I would have suggested.